# What's the difference between System.Diagnostics.Trace, System.Diagnostics.Debug and System.Console?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, logging, diagnostics

As far as I understand, `System.Console` will write to STDOUT by default, but what about `System.Diagnostics.Trace` and `System.Diagnostics.Debug`? What are the default behaviors, and are they configurable in any way?

It also seems that different people use different things (on the internet), but I'm assuming that most of what I've found is wrong, since there should be specific semantics for each of these, right? And if so, are there any frameworks (like ASP.NET or WPF) that make special use of these?

Also one last question, what are the rules of thumb for picking which one of these to use?

Comment: I think most people simply skip built-in tracing support in .Net and go from `printf`-tracing to some bigger library like NLog... Good links for .Net tracing are collected by Stephen Cleary in [Simple and Easy Tracing in .NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/12/simple-and-easy-tracing-in-net.html).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Debug` and `Trace` both write out to the same location, the `Listeners` collection. By default it is routed to Visual Studio's Debug window, however [you can put code in your `app.config` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to redirect it to other locations when you are not debugging.

The difference between `Debug` and `Trace` is  all of the methods in `Debug` only write out when the `DEBUG` compilation symbol is set (default on for debug, off for release) when the symbol is not set the methods are never called in your code. Trace looks for the TRACE symbol (default on for both debug and release). Other that that, the two classes are identical. In fact if you modify `Debug.Listeners` to add a new listener it will also modify `Trace.Listeners` as both just point to the internal static property `TraceInternal.Listeners`

As for picking which one to use, Do you want diagnostic information to show up in release and debug mode? use Trace, Debug only? use Debug. Do you want it to be visible to a end user without a debugger attached? use Console or add a console trace listener.

Comment: +1. To be really precise by default output send to "debugger to display" via [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and VS normally happen to be "the debugger", but indeed it can be seen in other debuggers (like WinDbg) or special tools like [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647)